# Get Entries from Section related to a category

Tags: entries, categories, sections

I'm currently trying to get all entries which belong to a section which is related to that category. e.g.

- Category

  - Brand

    - Offer

Offer belongs to a brand.

Brand has a category field.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('offers').relatedTo(category).find() %}
```

Currently trying the above, but returns nothing.

Thanks

-- EDIT --

The offer entries belong to a brand, a brand section belongs to a category. I'm trying to fetch all offers of all the brands which belong to a category.

Comment: Your code works for me. Did you make sure you fetched the correct category and your category field is not inside a matrix?

Comment: Doesn't work for me, the code works but it doesn't return anything. The Section is correct. This is being called on the category page itself.

Comment: yeah but is your relation field in a matrix? because you can't revert search related entries inside matrix elements

Comment: Is this an entry where you have a category field & you are trying to display a button with the brand link and name of that category. Or is this a category and you want to show all entries related to it?

Comment: Edited the question. They are not in a matrix.

Comment: There is no default way to connect a section with a category. Did you create a custom field in your category that links to a section? You can only relate elements with each other and sections are no elements. Maybe your structure does not really fit to the mechanics in Craft or I am not able to understand your explanation.

Comment: Check what the value of `category` is: `{% dump(category) %}`. Check that without the `relatedTo` you get all the entries: `{% dump(craft.entries.section('offers').find()) %}` Maybe that will give you a clue to what is going wrong.